# Limiting and restricted to

Tags: word-usage

I understand what these two words mean. However, when I construct a sentence using these two, I become confused what my sentence actually means.

In particular,

1. I am restricted to the basement area. (Does it mean I should only be at the basement area or I am not allowed to go there?)
2. People always work overtime, limiting them to take part in leisure activities. (Did I express clearly what I want to say? I think it means "they are only allowed to take part in leisure activities)
3. People always work overtime, limiting their time to take part in leisure activities (I think this is correct)

Answer (score 1):

*I am restricted to the basement area* = the basement is the only part of the building I am allowed in.

You could also say *My access is limited/restricted to the basement,* but I don't think you can say *I am limited.*

In the same way, your second sentence doesn't work. You would have to say that working overtime limits people's *opportunities* to take part in leisure activities. (Or *time*, as you have now put in your third sentence.)

Comment: I agree with your explanation but would add that the first sentence could mean that the basement is the only part of the building that I have permission to be in though there's nothing physically preventing me entering other rooms, but could also mean that I have been locked in the basement and literally can't get out.

Comment: Could add that restricted *to* is the opposite of restricted *from*.

Comment: The confusing part for many people is probably that "My access to the basement is restricted" and "I have restricted access to the basement" mean almost the exact opposite to "I am restricted to the basement". If I wasn't a native speaker it'd confuse me.

Comment: @BoldBen Do you mean to say "My access to the basement is restricted" (I am not allowed) is the opposite of "I am restricted to the basement" (I am only allowed in this area)? Now, I am confused again .

Comment: @Hydes What's confusing about it? "**I am restricted to the basement**" means "The only part of the building I can enter is the basement" (in other words I am not allowed to visit any of the other floors at all). On the other hand "**My access to the basement is restricted**" implies that you are allowed to visit all the other floors but says that you can only visit certain parts of the basement or that you can only visit at certain times. These are almost exactly opposite to each other.